# How to apply search on deep relation in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to apply search on the item members which is associated with the item.
I've members relation on my Item model like this

```
public function members()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            'App\Models\Users\TeamMember',
            ['App\Models\Users\Team'],
            [['teamable_type', 'teamable_id'], 'team_id'],
            ['id', 'id']
        );
    }
```

I've done this code for apply search on items on the bases of item's members

```
    $items = Item::query();
    ->where('title', 'Like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
    
    ->with('members')
    ->orWhereHas('members', function ($query) use($keyword) {
        $query->from('users')->where('name', 'Like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    })->get();
```

this relation will be return an array of members. Now It's giving me error called -

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'team_members.team_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `items` and `title` Like %test% or exists
```

Comment: Does the column team_members.team_id exists in the table ?

Comment: Yes.. I've team_id in team_members table